# missing 'knit pdf' in rstudio ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am not able to see the "knit pdf" option in the latest version of rstudio, knitr, rmarkdown in ubuntu system. Is it not available for ubuntu system ? I did not find any ifnormation like that in the web. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `output: pdf_document` in your yaml? Rstudio only shows knit for selected output. If you do, please be more specific, maybe with a screenshot

Answer (score -1):

Is the file you are working with in .Rnw format? If it isn't RSTUDIO won't show you the 'compile pdf' option.

Comment: I have .rmd file, In Ubuntu, is the  "knit pdf" option available only for .Rnw files?